# Using a function to slowly increase the background colors' numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to slowly increase the color of a background with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        let container = document.querySelector(".container")
        for(let i = 0 ; i<50; i++) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                container.style.background = `rgb(${i} , ${i}, ${i})`},
                1000);
            }
</script>
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working. It doesn't seem to iterate correctly when I console.log(i). I want it to pause for every iteration. How do I do this?

Comment: you are running the settimeout 50 times at the same time. not 50 times each one separeted by 1 second

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this issue by multiplying `i` with `setTimeout` delay like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      container.style.background = `rgb(${i} , ${i}, ${i})`
   }, 1000 * i);  // <----- like this
}
```

**DEMO:**

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container")
for (let i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12777215).toString(16);

    container.style.background = `rgb(${i} , ${i}, ${i})`
    
  }, 1000 * i);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100px;height:100px"></div>
```

**Demo (from black to white):**

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container")
let container2 = document.querySelector(".container2")
for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    container.style.background = `rgb(${i} , ${i}, ${i})`
    container2.textContent = `rgb(${i} , ${i}, ${i})`
  }, 50 * i);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:200px;height:100px"></div>
<div class="container2" style="width:200px;height:100px"></div>
```

Comment: What I wanted is for the loop to go from 0 to 255, but even from 0 to 50, the iteration jumps from 0 to 10 to 20 to 30 to 40 to 50. I'm not sure why. I want the iteration to go 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...255. Apologies if my explanation wasn't clear.

Comment: I have added a new demo. Yuo can see div background is changing from rgb(0 , 0, 0) to rgb(255 , 255, 255). You can increase `setTimeout` delay from 50 to 1000 if you need but the change will be very slow to notice for the users.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is asynchrone

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let container = document.querySelector(".container")
    let i = 0;
    function nextTimeout(){
      setTimeout(function() {
            container.style.background = `rgb(${i} , ${i}, ${i})`;
            i++;
            if(i<50){
              console.log('next');
              nextTimeout()
            }
          },
      1000);

    }
    nextTimeout();                 
</script>
```